# invalid use of class::constroctor not sure what the problem is. However when using set method there's no problem

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

constructor of base class

```
Business::Business(const string& nName,const string& nAddress) {    name
= nName;    address = nAddress; }
```

constructor that i am trying to use from derived class

```
Restaurant::Restaurant(const float& nRating,const string& nName,const string& nAddress)
        {
            Business();
            Business::setBusinessName(nName);
            Business::setBusinessAddress(nAddress);
            rating = nRating;
            
        }
```

from main I am trying to set the fields of the class from main using the above method which uses the constructor from restaurant class. I keep on getting error invalid use of 'Restaurant::Restaurant'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Restaurant.h"



int main()
{
    Restaurant m;
    
    m.Restaurant(2.55 , "s" , "224");

    
    cout << m.getRating() <<endl<< m.getBusinessAddress() <<endl<< m.getBusinessName();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ratio of the usefulness of [the Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) vs  the frequency at which it is taught borders on infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of your base class construction off your derived class is wrong. It should look like this:

```
Restaurant::Restaurant(const float& nRating,const string& nName,const string& nAddress)
    : Business(nName, nAddress) // base construction
    , rating(nRating)           // member initialization
{
}
```

By the looks of it, your entire understanding of how constructors work is equally wrong. In `main()`, this:

```
Restaurant m;
m.Restaurant(2.55 , "s" , "224");
```

Should simply be:

```
Restaurant m(2.55 , "s" , "224");
```